# Jekyll is not correctly reading page title

Tags: jekyll

I'm running into a new error after updating to the newest version of Jekyll, where it's giving me an

Here is part of the error message after running `jekyll build`:

```
___________________________________________________________________________
| Maruku tells you:
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Bad block-level HTML:
| |#<MaRuKu::Exception: Error: Malformed: tag <p> closes <a>
| |HTML READER
| | state=inside_element match="</p>"
| |Tag stack = ["ul", "li", "a"]
| |Before:
| ||<ul class="compact recent">
| ||<li>
| ||    <a href="/blog/hello-world.html" title="<p>Hello everyone&#8212;just getting    the website set up, so it might take a while for more to appear here.</p>
| |After:
| ||">Hello world!</a>
```

The post in question consists of:

```
--- 
layout: blog-post
title: "Hello world!"
published: true
---

Hello everyone---just getting the website set up, so it might take a while for more to appear here.

Check back later for information about my research, papers, etc.
```

While the page running into the error is using:

```
<ul class="compact recent">
{% for post in site.categories.blog limit:3 %}
<li>
    <a href="{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.excerpt }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    <span class="date">{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</span> 
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Any ideas as to why it isn't getting the title properly? This worked fine in an earlier version of jekyll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `title` attribute, and making sure the posted code block was separated by the previous text by an empty line, fixed this problem.